# Rails refuses to insert one field into the database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Basically I grab an the id of an element from a table and insert it into another.

```
vuln_id = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT FROM BLAH WHERE ...")                   

pid = vuln_id.first

puts "=============================="
puts pid # this echos the ID
puts "=============================="

if pid.empty? 
    puts "pid is empty"
end

rd = Report.new(:plugin_id => pid, :report_id => report_id)
rd.save()
```

In Rails console, when I do

`Report.dbaction(params)`

It runs the model and here is the output

```
(0.3ms)  SELECT STATEMENT.....
==============================
186
==============================
(3.0ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `report_data` (`created_at`, `report_id`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2013-07-10 22:03:59', 6, '2013-07-10 22:03:59')
(33.9ms)  COMMIT
```

It inserts `report_id` but it doesnt insert `pid` value into the database, even though it exists. Why is this?

Quick edit: plugin_id definitely exists in the table. I triple checked.

Here is what the rest of the model file looks like

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :site
    has_many :plugins
```

Comment: It's running rails 4. Been stuck on this for over an hour now, I'm sure it's something obvious...

Comment: Could you please share with us your models? Thanks.

Comment: This is from the model file, I also updated the initial post with the top of the model file

Comment: This is so weird, I tried `:plugin_id => "999"` and the query worked fine. I'm assuming that the initial value is not validating as an integer

Comment: I tried `pid.to_i` which gives me `NoMethodError: undefined method 'to_i' for [186]:Array` Not sure how to convert this into an integer

Comment: `pid` is an `array` as your console states, you could just grab the first item and then convert it to an integer. => `pid.first.to_i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the first result from the database query in line 1 but `execute` returns an array of arrays, I believe, that contains all the columns that you selected. You probably want: `pid = vuln_id.first[0]` or something like that (or `pid = vuln_id[0][0]` or pid = `vuln_id.first.first`).

You should also verify that the query returned anything at all so the entire line might be something like:

```
pid = vuln_id.first.first if vuln_id and vuln_id.count > 0
```